# sql subquery resulting the unwanted braces with result

Tags: oracle, plsql

i am having big query where i am using one below subquery but that is returning  unwanted braces ...

```
SUBSTR(work__note.note_text,1,10000) || '  ' ||  (select user_name from cm_use where SEQ_USER_ID in work_request_note.create_user_id) || '   ' || work__note.create_date   "Notes"
```

this is giving below output :

"Work was assigned to Kristie Cut (ard1)   01-NOV-23"

desired output : "Work  was assigned to Kristie Cutt klcd1   01-NOV-23"

SUBSTR(work_note.note_text,1,10000) || '  ' ||  (select user_name from cm_use where SEQ_USER_ID in work__note.create_user_id) || '   ' || work_note.create_date   "Notes"

```
this is giving below output :

"Work Request was assigned to Kri Cut (kld1)   01-NOV-23"

desired output : "Work  was assigned to Kris Cup kld1   01-NOV-23"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use [Replace function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/REPLACE.html#GUID-1A79BDDF-2D3B-4AD4-98E7-985B2E59DA6B) to get ridd of braces. If your result is like in the question you can do it on resulting string:

```sql
Select    Replace(  Replace('Work Request was assigned to Kristie Cupitt (klccard1)   01-NOV-23', 
                            '(', ''
                           ), 
                  ')', ''
                 ) "TXT"
From Dual 

--  TXT                                                             
--  ----------------------------------------------------------------
--  Work Request was assigned to Kristie Cupitt klccard1   01-NOV-23
```

... Or (better) on column that containes braces. In this sample I would say that it is USER_NAME from table CMS_USER. If that is so, then your subquery, changed like below, should give you expected result.

```sql
(select Replace(Replace(user_name, '(', ''), ')', '') "USER_NAME" from cms_user where SEQ_USER_ID in work_request_note.create_user_id)
```

BTW: your SUBSTR(work_request_note.note_text,1,10000) part does not make sense since SubStr is character function and columns of that type could have max length of 4000 so if you want the whole text than there is no need for SubStr at all. You could just put  work_request_note.note_text instead. On the other hand if you ommit the last parameter then you will get the result untill the end of string whatever length it could be...

Comment: Replace is also not working and giving the braces

Comment: @Vimal Replace IS working as shown above, but we have no insight in your actual data and there is no sample data provided so it is hard to tell what is the issue. If you could provide some sample data and the code  that works wrong against that data then we will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0):

You said that result contains "unwanted" braces. These are - I presume - contained in `cms_user.user_name` column.

> Does that mean that there are also "wanted" braces? If so, what about them? How do you know which ones are wanted, and which are not?

You can replace them, or - maybe a little bit simpler - use `translate` function (see [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/MebvRPy-) for demo). Also, why didn't you join tables being involved, but used a subquery to get username?

Therefore, how about

```
select w.note_text                        ||' '|| 
       translate(c.user_name, 'x()', 'x') ||' '|| 
       w.create_date as notes
from work_request_note w join cms_user c on c.seq_user_id = w.create_user_id
```

Comment: This is wrong as it will remove `)` and `x` characters and replace `(` with `x`. To fix it you want to use `TRANSLATE(c.user_name, 'x()', 'x')` (which will replace `x` with `x` and remove `(` and `)` characters).

Comment: yeah its replacing ( with x , we need to take out (

Comment: It shouldn't. Did you correctly type parameters of TRANSLATE function?